# Use variables set in a select statement

Tags: mysql, sql

Can I use a variable I set in a `select` statement?

I want to do something like this (which obviously isn't working):

```
SELECT 
    YEAR(date_of_spend), 
    @current := SUM(spend_amount),
    @half := (SUM(spend_amount) / 2),
    (@current - @half)
FROM `sales_data`
GROUP BY YEAR(date_of_spend)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. According to mysql manual:

> As a general rule, you should never assign a value to a user variable
>   and read the value within the same statement. You might get the
>   results you expect, but this is not guaranteed. The order of
>   evaluation for expressions involving user variables is undefined and
>   may change based on the elements contained within a given statement;
>   in addition, this order is not guaranteed to be the same between
>   releases of the MySQL Server.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/user-variables.html

You need to repeat the expressions again or use a subquery

Comment: Does MySQL run the calculations twice?

Comment: It's not a documented optimisation, so I would not count much on it, especially since the big focus on optimisation lies usually on the joins. It should not be difficult to test it. You also have the option of using a subquery which will avoid the double computation but might need more memory (depends also on the optimiser).

Answer (score -1):

Just need to set them:

```
SELECT 
    YEAR(date_of_spend), 
    @current := SUM(spend_amount),
    @half := (SUM(spend_amount) / 2),
    (@current - @half)
FROM `sales_data`,
    (SELECT @current := 0, @half := 0) r
GROUP BY YEAR(date_of_spend)
```

[See the demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/19182/1).

Comment: That just makes `@current - @half` return 0. They are set on lines 3 and 4.

Comment: Yes I know if I changed to to out use the function instead of the variable it would work. However this is a simplified example, and the calculation is much larger in practice.